# TempData Message in different tab

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

i want in my page after an action like RegisterUser give a message to client for result.so i use TempData(becase i use RedirectToAction method i cant use viewbag).my problem is that if user open another tab in same time message will show in another tab(any page it can be).how can i solve that??

```
  @using (@Html.BeginForm("RegisterUser", "UserManagement", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @Html.Partial("_RegisterPagesMessage")
    <table class="Registertbl">
        <tr>
            <td>نام*</td>
            <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FName, new { maxlength = 20})<br />
            </td>               
            <td>سمت*</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Post, new { maxlength = 200})</td>                
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Insert" class="insertBtn" />
        @Html.ActionLink("back", "ViewUserList", "UserManagement")
}
```

//_RegisterPagesMessage

```
@if (TempData["MessageResult"] == null)
{
    <div id="ErrorContent" class="msg-Red" style="display: none;"></div>  <br />                  
}
else
{
    <div id="ErrorContent"  class="@TempData["cssClass"]"  >
            @Html.Label(TempData["MessageResult"] as string)
    </div>  <br />   
}
```

//Controller

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RegisterUser()
    {
        return View(new User());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult RegisterUser(Common.UsersManagement.Entities.User model)
    {
        SetUserManagement();
        var Result = userManagement.RegisterUser(model);
SetMessage(Result.Mode.ToString());
        if (Result.Mode == Common.Extensions.ActionResultMode.Successfully)
        {
                return RedirectToAction("RegisterUser");
        }
         // if not Successfull
        return View(model);
    }    
  protected void SetMessage(string Mode)
        {
            var messageResult = XmlReader.FindMessagekey(Mode);
            TempData["MessageResult"] = messageResult.MessageContent;
            TempData["cssClass"] = messageResult.cssClass;
        }
```

Comment: Does the user open the same action url i.e. RegisterUser in new tab?

Comment: he can do this for this page or any other page.

Comment: How does it matter if user opens another page in a different tab? You are using the Temp data values on a single view only, so it will appear on that view only.

Comment: i use this partial page(_RegisterPagesMessage) on other page.so .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution. In your RegisterUser controller method check for a value in TempData and transfer it to ViewData, then have the View check the ViewData, which only survives for that one view.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult RegisterUser()
{
    if( TempData.ContainsKey( "MessageResult" )
    {
        ViewData["MessageResult"] = TempData["MessageResult"];
        ViewData["cssClass"] = messageResult.cssClass;
    }

    return View(new User());
}
```

Now in the view use ViewData instead of TempData.